# JQuery val() not working on input from php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, input

i'm trying to retrieve the value of an input using JQuery's val().
I've used this before and worked well, but I'm having troubles even with the same code.

The input fields are included by php include() in the page. Can this be the problem?

This is the code of the included fields:

```
<input type="text" id="nome" /></br>
<input type="text" id="cognome" /></br>
<input type="text" id="societa" /></br>
<select id="categoria">
    <option value="RM">Ragazzi</option>
    <option value="CM">Cadetti</option>
    <option value="AM">Allievi</option>
    <option value="JM">Junior</option>
    <option value="PM">Promesse</option>
    <option value="SM">Assoluti</option>
</select></br>
<input type="text" id="accredito" /></br>
```

And this is the JQuery

```
var squadra = $('#societa').val();
var nome = $('#nome').val();
var cognome = $('#cognome').val();
var categoria = $('#categoria').val();
var accredito = $('#accredito').val();
alert( squadra + nome + cognome + categoria + accredito );
```

JQuery variables remains all empty after calling the function.

Thanks in advance for the help

EDIT: Sorry, the problem was multiple input with the same ID in the same page >.<

Comment: Where are you calling your jQuery code? Did you wrapped it in [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the val() once the user has entered the data... Then, it should be ok. E.g. creating a function:

```
$('#alertValues').click(function(){
var squadra = $('#societa').val();
var nome = $('#nome').val();
var cognome = $('#cognome').val();
var categoria = $('#categoria').val();
var accredito = $('#accredito').val();
alert( squadra + nome + cognome + categoria + accredito );
});
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/axt9LaLm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for selected option value, rather than select tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert($('#categoria option:selected').val());
});
```

Comment: `societa` is a `input` so it doesn't have option as children and also `.val()` is valid and correct for selected tag